# Redirect from OAuth callback to popup behavior

Tags: javascript, security, redirect, oauth-2.0, popup

I'm currently implementing a generic callback for multiple OAuth providers, and for some  reasons, the redirect behavior isn't the same for Firefox.

```
  return {
    statusCode: 302,
    headers: {
      Location: 'http://localhost:3000/callback/success'
    }
  }
}
```

I'm triggering a test function happening in a Popup. Calling first test signin, which is opening the signin URL in a popup. Then once auth is passed (e.g: google oauth2.0) it redirects to my callback function.
So when I'm using this code as callback from sign-in function, in Chrome, Safari and Opera, the redirect is happening to the popup, but in Firefox, redirect is happening in the parent windows, which is making the interface loading the redirect rather than having it in the popup.

Is there any reason why redirect from backend is not working in the popup with Firefox?

Here's the code I'm using to open the popup with the new location (URL)

```
const width = 700
const height = 500
var left = (screen.width/2)-(width/2)
var top = (screen.height/2)-(height/2)

window.open(
new_location,'popUpWindow',`height=${height},width=${width},left=${left},top=${top},resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=yes,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no, status=yes`
)
```

Comment: This does not makes sense to me , all that i would suggest it so reset your preferences in Firefox and clean up the cache , it could be something that is causing this issue...

Comment: Do you reckon that `window.open` popup code is correct there?

Comment: Yes the code is fine ....

Comment: check if popup blocked or not in your firefox. or check if you are using any ad-blocker like extension,

Comment: Thanks, that's a good point, it doesn't work either.

Comment: Buddy.. did you manage to find out what is wrong...

Comment: Not yet, I did find a temporary fix which consists in opening a new tab rather than a popup